# Can lombok generate both static and non static constructors?

Tags: java, lombok

I have a simple `dto` class

```java
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of", access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class MyClass {
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;
}
```

I need to have both constructors `static` and `non-static`. If I delombok constructors

```java
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class MyClass{
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;

    private MyClass(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1= field1;
        this.field2= field2;
    }

    public static MyClass of(String field1, String field2) {
        return new MyClass(field1, field2);
    }
}
```

It's almost what I need but the `non-static` constructor is `private`. Is it possible to make it `public` with lombok?

Comment: 'static constructor' is a contradiction in terms. The term you are looking for is probably 'factory method'.

Comment: Is using `@AllArgsConstructor` an option for you?

Comment: I just use lombok's terminology see `staticName` in `RequiredArgsConstructor` `Name of static 'constructor' method to generate`

Comment: If I add `@AllArgsConstructor` there is an error `Error:(21, 1) java: constructor .... is already defined in class ....`

Comment: What's the point of this? The only reason to have a static factory method in addition to a constructor is to have some sort of optimization or special behavior code, which is something Lombok couldn't provide you anyway.

Comment: The point is to migrate the project to use lombok without changing a lot of code as both constructors are used now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Lombok (at least not in the current version 1.18.12). 
Consider reviewing the JavaDoc [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.java#L44). It says that setting the *staticName* property will mark the constructor private. It does not specify explicitly that it will ignore the *access* property, but in practice it appears it does.

It is usually considered bad practice to provide multiple ways to achieve the same result, in this case creating a class instance with the same parameters. 
Given the fact that your code already uses both, you might consider creating the static builder methods manually and marking one technique as deprecated, to prevent its future use until completely refactoring it out.

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Deprecated))
public class MyClass {
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;

    public static MyClass of(String field1, String field2) {
        return new MyClass(field1, field2);
    }
}
```

or:

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;

    /**
     * @deprecated Will be removed in the future.
     *    Use {@link #MyClass(String, String)} instead 
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static MyClass of(String field1, String field2) {
        return new MyClass(field1, field2);
    }
}
```